# atmel 89c2051 setting or clearing individual register bits in C

Tags: c, atmel

I am programming an atmel 89c2051 controller. I want to make conditions based on the status of each individual register bits for example:

do (something something) while port 1 bit 0 is 0

I've tried using while P1_0 but the compiler returns an undeclared identifier error. How do I go about in doing this? thanks

Comment: I think you have to call some sort of read-from-that-port function.

Comment: Please give your compiling message.

Comment: compiling distance.C...
distance.C(14): warning C206: 'disonecount': missing function-prototype
distance.C(16): warning C206: 'distwocount': missing function-prototype
distance.C(18): warning C206: 'disthreecount': missing function-prototype
distance.C(20): warning C206: 'disfourcount': missing function-prototype
distance.C(24): warning C265: 'main': recursive call to non-reentrant function
distance.C(60): error C202: 'P1_1': undefined identifier
Target not created

Answer (score 0):

Mask your port variable, and then do a simple true/false test. For example:

```
while (PIND & (1<<PD1))
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

The above code creates a new "mask" variable, which is `1` shifted over to the position of `PD1` (the actual variable is `0b00000010`, or `0x02`). That "mask" is then `AND`ed with the pins read: everything becomes `0` (because both bits have to be `1` for the result to be `1`), other than the bit in the position you are testing for. The result is either `0` or some number greater than `0`, which will evaluate to `true` in the boolean test.